# How to scroll up to div inside another div in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a button I want to scroll the window up to a specific div (temp-class).
I tried but it doesn't work. I think it's because of CSS styles. But I can't remove the styles.
below is my code

```
<body>
<div class="m-portlet m-portlet-no-bdr">
    <div class="abc">{{}}</div>
    <div class="abc">{{}}</div>
    <div class="abc">{{}}</div>
    <div class="temp-class">{{}}</div>
    <div class="abc">{{}}</div>
</div>

 .m-portlet-no-bdr {
        min-height: calc(100vh - 130px);
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: calc(100vh - 172px);
        overflow-x: hidden;
 }

$('.m-portlet-no-bdr').animate(
{
  scrollTop: $('.m-portlet-no-bdr').scrollTop() + ($('.temp-class').offset().top - $('.m-portlet-no-bdr').offset().top)
});
```

Comment: Have you tried the anchor element method? By clicking it it will automatically move to that element which has that class ```<a href="className">ButtonName</a>```

Answer (score 1):

i fixed the problem with below way

```
  $('.m-portlet-no-bdr').animate(
   {
    scrollTop: $('.m-portlet-no-bdr').scrollTop() + $('*:contains('+errors[0]+'):last').offset().top - 172
  });
```

what i previously did is, i added "temp-class" to the place which "errors[0]" is exist.

```
$(':contains("' + errors[0] + '")').addClass('temp-class');
```

I think it was the problem. I could fix the problem in this way.
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use [document.documentElement, document.body] instead of '.m-portlet-no-bdr':

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: $(".temp-class").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

See example in playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/5zceag1w/12/

Comment: after removing style="height:500px" it's not warking...just copy and paste few more             "<div class="abc">{{}}</div> " and what i need is after event firing " <div class="temp-class">{{}}</div>" should be top of the screen.